# how to register with an event handler that is in a user control in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I've got a user control that represents an employee. The xaml is an image of a character icon and there is a textbox for the employee name.
When text is typed into the textbox the Textchanged event is raised and this event handler is called:

```
private void employeeNameChangedEventHandler(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            _employeeName = employeeName.Text;
        }
```

The is a property in the user control so the name can be retrieved:

```
 public string EmployeeName
        {
            get { return _employeeName; }
        }
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs I want to listen to the TextChanged eventhandler in the user control.

I've read up about delegates and have a bit of experience with events from Unity but just not sure the best way to implement this in wpf.

Ta

Comment: I don't understand what what you want. If you want to use binding with dependency property, then create dependency property in your user control. If you want to get access to your user control in the main window code, then assign a name to your user control and call user control via its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use customer routed event.
In your Usercontrol, you need add your routed event, like this:

```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent NameChangedEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent

               ("NameChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>), typeof(UserControl1));

        public event RoutedEventHandler NameChanged
        {

            add { this.AddHandler(NameChangedEvent, value); }

            remove { this.RemoveHandler(NameChangedEvent, value); }

        }
```

And In your textchanged event of textbox, you should raise your customer routed event.

```
 private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(UserControl1.NameChangedEvent));
        }
```

Now you just need add subscribe your customer routed event where you need your usercontrol  as you do use textchanged.

```
<local:UserControl1 x:Name="uc" NameChanged="NameChanged"/>
```

And the NameChanged is like this

```
 private void NameChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //when you input one character in you usercontrol, you will get here
        }
```

Comment: me.. Thx! I get the overall idea - but could you explain what the line ("NameChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(EventHandler<RoutedEventArgs>), typeof(UserControl1)) is doing?